where are the standard rules that can interpret the issue of the wrong check in `std::shared_ptr`
Consider this example:
a.h
#pragma once
#include <memory>

struct AAA;
std::shared_ptr<AAA> createAAA();


a.cpp
#include "A.h"
struct AAA : public std::enable_shared_from_this<AAA>{};
void destory_AAA(AAA* v) {
    v->~AAA();
}
std::shared_ptr<AAA> createAAA() {
    auto ret = std::make_shared<AAA>();
    // check if shared_from_this is OK after make_shared
    auto shared_from_ths = ret->shared_from_this();  // #1
    return shared_from_ths;
}

main.cpp
#include "A.h"
void destory_AAA(AAA* v);
std::shared_ptr<AAA> unused_func(AAA* ptr) {
    return std::shared_ptr<AAA>{ ptr, destory_AAA };  // #2
}
int main()
{
    createAAA();
}

In this example, under the debug mode of certain MSVC, #1 throws an error bad weak_ptr. Some guys say the ODR rule causes this problem [basic.def.odr] p15. However, I think the template definition of std::shared_ptr does not violate those rules.
What is the rule in the C++ standard that interprets the reason of the problem? I suspect the rule is [temp.res.general] p6:

The validity of a templated entity may be checked prior to any instantiation.  The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:


[...]
the interpretation of such a construct in the hypothetical instantiation is different from the interpretation of the corresponding construct in any actual instantiation of the templated entity.



Both #1 and #2 will cause the following templated function instantiated
    template <class _Ux>
    void _Set_ptr_rep_and_enable_shared(_Ux* const _Px, _Ref_count_base* const _Rx) noexcept { // take ownership of _Px
        this->_Ptr = _Px;
        this->_Rep = _Rx;
        if constexpr (conjunction_v<negation<is_array<_Ty>>, negation<is_volatile<_Ux>>, _Can_enable_shared<_Ux>>) {
            if (_Px && _Px->_Wptr.expired()) {
                _Px->_Wptr = shared_ptr<remove_cv_t<_Ux>>(*this, const_cast<remove_cv_t<_Ux>*>(_Px));
            }
        }
    }

However, in the TU main.cpp, the struct AAA is incomplete while it is complete in the a.cpp. Is this the correct rule that interprets the problem? Is ODR rule relevant here?

My wild guess is that ODR violation is here as "some guys" said. You have two sets of generated functions template std::shared_ptr - one in a.cpp when A is known to have the shared_ptr control block inside (enable_shared_from_this) -- the other set of functions in main.cpp where A is "unknown" type. Probably differences in MSVC debug mode are so important that random selecting of these functions causes problems. But that just only my guessing, someone with better expertise in MSVC debug mode could answer to this.

Which version of msvc are you using? Probably unrelated to your question but note that the implementation of destory_AAA is incorrect and should be delete v

Unrelated, but destroy_AAA shouldn't exist, because all instances should be owned by shared pointers, because it inherits enable_shared_from_this

@PiotrNycz You have two sets of generated functions template std::shared_ptr ODR rules does not apply to generated/instantiated entity.

Can't reproduce in VS 2022 17.10.4
